# Открытие и закрытие картинки/текста анимацией в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, qlabel, qgraphicsopacityeffect

Как с анимацией выводить картинку/текст и через время закрывать его, такой же анимацией, мой код на данный момент:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()                               # !!!
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)                    # !!!
        
        self.lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("lena-2.png").scaled(400, 400)      # ваше фото
        self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pix)
        
        self.btn = QPushButton()
        self.btn.setText("Кнопка")
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("""
            background: pink; 
            color: black; 
            border-radius: 34px;
        """)
        self.btn.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn.setFixedSize(300, 150)
        self.btn.setCheckable(True)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.show_image)

        layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl, 0, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn, 1, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)
        
        self.eff = QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
        self.eff.setOpacity(0.0)        
        self.lbl.setGraphicsEffect(self.eff)
        
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.eff, b'opacity')
        self.animation.setDuration(3000)       
        
    def show_image(self):
        if not self.btn.isChecked():       
            self.animation.setStartValue(1)
            self.animation.setEndValue(0)
        else:    
            self.animation.setStartValue(0)
            self.animation.setEndValue(1)            
        self.animation.start() 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.resize(420, 600)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `QTimer` предоставляет повторяющиеся и однократные таймеры.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html

```
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(7000, self.btn.click)
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()                              
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)                  
        
        self.lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("lena-2.png").scaled(400, 400)      # ваше фото
        self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pix)
        
        self.btn = QPushButton()
        self.btn.setText("Кнопка")
        self.btn.setStyleSheet("""
            background: pink; 
            color: black; 
            border-radius: 34px;
        """)
        self.btn.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Pusia-Bold.otf", 17, QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        self.btn.setFixedSize(300, 150)
        self.btn.setCheckable(True)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.show_image)

        layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.lbl, 0, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn, 1, 0, Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)
        
        self.eff = QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
        self.eff.setOpacity(0.0)        
        self.lbl.setGraphicsEffect(self.eff)
        
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.eff, b'opacity')
        self.animation.setDuration(3000)       
        
    def show_image(self):
        if not self.btn.isChecked():       
            self.animation.setStartValue(1)
            self.animation.setEndValue(0)
        else:    
            self.animation.setStartValue(0)
            self.animation.setEndValue(1)
            
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(7000, self.btn.click)   # !!! 3000 + 4000 = 7000 

        self.animation.start() 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.resize(420, 600)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]